# What does "The map g be geometrically interpreted as the stereographic projection of the Gauss map" mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

What does "The map g be geometrically interpreted as the stereographic projection of the Gauss map" mean?
I already researched this but I do not find anything about this "interpretation".

Following is an article print:[image]

Comment: From a pedestrian perspective, the authors mean that if you compute the Gauss map of the immersion $\Phi(z)$, which is a mapping from the surface (namely, I guess, $\widetilde{\Sigma \backslash \{ p_j\}} $) into a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and then take its stereographic projection (from this sphere onto $\mathbb{R}^2$, suitably identified with $\mathbb{C}$), then you should be able to recover the mapping $g$. I can't help you with the details, sorry :)

Comment: For the curious, this is a Weierstrass-Enneper representation of minimal surfaces, and the verifications can be found, e.g. [in this course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-994-seminar-in-geometry-fall-2004/), see [Lecture 20](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-994-seminar-in-geometry-fall-2004/lecture-notes/chapter18.pdf) there.